# How to use Get-AzKeyVaultSecret in Powershell Azure Function 2.x

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I'm setting up a Powershell Azure Function that needs keys from an Azure KeyVault. Most of the keys can be retrieved by using the @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri='MySecretUriWithVersion') method.

One of the keys changes frequently. Hence the SecretUri cannot be used.

All keys are stored in the same KeyVault and the Function has a MSI that can read, list and change all keys.

I'm working with a refresh token that needs to be updated. This value is renewed every time my code runs and needs to be updated in the keyvault

```bsh
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

#Works
Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $VaultName -ResourceGroupName $rgName

#Not working
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $KeyName
```

Expected output: The code retrieves the key.

> Actual output: ERROR: Operation returned an invalid status code
>   'Unauthorized' Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Rpc.RpcException :
>   Result: ERROR: Operation returned an invalid status code
>   'Unauthorized' Exception: Operation returned an invalid status code
>   'Unauthorized' Stack:    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync(String
>   vaultBaseUrl, String secretName, String secretVersion, Dictionary`2
>   customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   dlet.ProcessRecord()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original error is fixed in Azure Functions now.

It is still necessary to retrieve keys that are updated frequently in key vault. To do that, I use this:

```
(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret MyVaultName -Name MySecretName).secretvalue | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText
```

Comment: "ConvertFrom-SecureString : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AsPlainText'."

Comment: What version are you on? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Powershell version: 5.1.19041.906

Answer (score 3):

Taken from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-powershell

Have you tried dot notation on retrieving those keys?

```
(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -vaultName $VaultName -name $KeyName).SecretValueText
```

If that doesn't work, you may look at this github issue regarding ManagedAppServices: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8983

Seems to be the same issue you're having.

Comment: Yes. That is the issue I'm facing. Thanks for pointing me to the right bug :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is now a new method for this.

```
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "<your-unique-keyvault-name>" -Name "ExamplePassword"
$ssPtr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secret.SecretValue)
try {
  $secretValueText = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($ssPtr)
} finally {
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($ssPtr)
}
Write-Output $secretValueText
```

Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Also, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/62396) if you face any issues due to `secretValueText` being deprecated.